# javascript array filter by objects containg name pattern and date time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to exclude some entries from an array like so :

```
Array = [ 
   Object,
   Object,
   Object
   ...
]
```

and `Object`  looks like this

```
Object = {
    name : 'IT_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422',
    lastModified : timeinmilliseconds (number)
}
```

`Object` name property can start with different values like IT, KK, MN, followed by _ and ThisNameIsConstant is the same.

I want to keep 3 entryes for every IT, KK, MN ... etc based on either the date contained in the name, or lastModified property number.

The Array is not sorted so objects can be scrambled with IT then KK then IT , IT , KK, MN, IT, MN ... etc

Thanks

Comment: How did you want your result to be ?

Comment: just removed from the array ... doesnt matter .. but i find it hard to think of a solution :( i-m thinking of creating a temporary array (set) to hold the reference for every prefix ... :((

Comment: Let's not make this overly complicated. Just do `var IT = arr.filter(e => e.name[0] == 'I');` and so on, then sort these arrays using a similar function, then pick the first three. Done.

Comment: yes but this not apply if IT and IK or something :( i think better use indexOf(name + delimiter) = indexOf('IT_')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. The array is traversed and categorized in to an object with `type` as `key` and maximum 3 different objects based on the `lastModified` as `value`.

```js
var a = [{name:"IT_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:123},{name:"IT_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:13},{name:"IT_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:1245323},{name:"MM_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:12334},{name:"NI_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:532},{name:"IT_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:12234124},{name:"MM_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:12312124},{name:"NI_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:531232},{name:"IM_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:123},{name:"MM_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:1444444334},{name:"MM_ThisNameIsContant_20180501_113422",lastModified:532}], result={};

a.forEach(function(elem){
    var type = elem.name.split("_").shift();
    result[type] = result[type] || [];
    result[type].push(elem);
});

Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key){
    var arr = result[key];
    arr = arr.filter(function(elem,index,arr){
       return arr.map(function(mapelem){
          return mapelem.lastModified;
       }).indexOf(elem.lastModified) === index;
    })         //Remove duplicates
    .sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; }); //Sort based on the lastModified
    
    arr.length=Math.min(arr.length,3); //Just keep a maximum of n=3 values
    
    result[key] = arr; //Re-assign the values to the object
});


console.log(result)
```

Please refer [this post](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/05/removing-duplicate-objects-array-property-name-javascript/) for efficient removal of duplicates which I have used.

Comment: I was writing an answer as well, but yours is much cleaner nicely done.

Comment: what if the first element in the array has a last modified older than other 3 elements that should be there?

Comment: I didn't consider the lesser or greater based on lastModified. I just filtered distinct objects based on the lastModified.

Comment: yes but if there is not result[type] first element is added right ?

Comment: but maybe the first element that is initialized there should not be there , if IT has 4 elements and the first one have an lastModified of 1278638173618736 and is first added ... then other element that should be there is skipped. so i was thinking .. to sort the array based on name and last modified and then just check if < 3

Comment: then the other element there with the same lastModified is skipped.. thats what you have asked for... right ?

Comment: i mean , if type IT have 5 elements , and 1st one have a last modified of 23487234792837492874 and other 4 have it in the range of (100 - 200) the result object witll contrain 3 elements but the first element for IT will be that with 234972948723948732947 last modified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172423/discussion-between-vignesh-raja-and-123onetwothree).